# IBM Worklight Hybrid App

Tags: wifi

I Exported Project as an .apk file and installed in My Android Mobile. When i am Using My Company WIFI In My App i am able check the entered user and update password if exist.

when i am connected to Mobile Network its not working.

Ex:- MyServer HostName:192.168.0.16. In My router I Done Portforwarding for 192.168.0.16 and 10080.. My LouterSystem IP Ex:-122.169.78.182.

I am Using SQL Adaptors to connect database.

Iam Getting Following error run app using android emulator:

03-03 04:16:32.358: D/HttpPostRequestSender(1135): WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:47 :: Sending request http://122.169.182.78:10800/Infraeasy/apps/services/api/DefaultPassword/android/query

03-03 04:16:32.608: I/Choreographer(1135): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

03-03 04:16:32.718: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(1135): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:154 :: onException

03-03 04:16:32.718: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(1135): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://122.169.182.78:10800 refused

Comment: "its not working". That's your problem, then.

Comment: using same network its working when iam connected using mobiledata its not contacting with mobilefirst server.. can u guide me were is the problem

Comment: Your greatest problem is that you do not seem to know what your problem is. Or, if you _do_ know what your problem is, you have not told us. Please add to your question the things you have tried, and what the result was, and what you expected the result to be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Mobilrfirst Server Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803423/ibm-mobilrfirst-server-issue)

Answer (score 0):

As in your duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803423/ibm-mobilrfirst-server-issue

The computer that you use to host the server, must be able to accept incoming connections from the public Internet, otherwise the application will not be able to connect to the server.

When the mobile phone and the server are in the same network, then the app is able to connect. Hence, you must verify that:

1. The server is able to accept connections from the public Internet
2. That there is no firewall blocking any ports and traffic
3. If you're getting any errors in LogCat (when you connect the device using a USB cable to your computer), tha would help debugging

Comment: idan i my wlclient.properties file wlServerHost = 192.168.0.16 ipaddress were MobileFirst server deployed in Development Machine. is it correct?

Comment: If you 2 ip addresses make sure you are pointing to the correct one. You must use the public ip address of your host

Comment: http://122.169.100.72:10080/worklightconsole iam using this address in browser its not showing worklight console.  above 122.169.100.72 is my public.. but wen i use local 192.168.0.220:10080/worklight its showing

Comment: Idan so its workling fine when server accept connection from publickly. what i did is I configured My router public ip address in wlclient.properties file which is located in appName/android/native/asset folder. wlServerHost = my public address and now its working in both WIFI and mobile data but the problem is any correction in app and publish into server then above property value changes into Mobile Server IP address. how to solve this

Comment: Change your server's host/ip to the public IP.  Open the Servers view in Eclipse and double-click on "mobilefirst development server". Change the hostname value to the public IP. Restart the server, re-build the application. This IP should now be in wlclient.properties by default.

Comment: No Idan After i chnaged HostName=My Public Server IP address its not server is not starting. its taking either localhost/Server System IPAddress

Comment: Then try using the remote server option in run as > server settings and remote target (forgot the correct name, but it's in run as). Put there the full hostname http://the-ip:10080/projectname

Comment: I have i doubt My Mobile First Server System and My Router System is diferrent.